# Aggregate() + quantile() with output as data frame

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am using `quantile()` within an `aggregate()`, see below.

The result is formatted as a data frame, however, as you can see in the `str()`, the actual quantiles are lists within a column. How do I get the output to be a data frame in which all 'columns' are actual columns (ie names(results) -->
"group" "subgroup" "value.0%" "value.25%" "value.50%" "value.75%" "value.100%"

(I don't care about the actual names, I just want to be able to use `setNames()`)

```
n=1000
df <- data.frame(group=sample(c("A", "B", "C"), n, replace=T), 
                 subgroup=sample(c("g1", "g2"), n, replace=T), 
                 value=sample(1:10000, n, replace=T))
head(df)

result <- aggregate(value ~ group + subgroup, df, function(x) quantile(x, probs = seq(0,1, 0.25)))

> result
  group subgroup value.0% value.25% value.50% value.75% value.100%
1     A       g1    26.00   3088.00   5738.00   7473.00    9852.00
2     B       g1    26.00   2450.00   4592.50   7319.00    9989.00
3     C       g1    17.00   2989.00   5565.00   7611.00    9944.00
4     A       g2    96.00   2843.75   4912.00   7719.50    9815.00
5     B       g2    77.00   2802.50   4725.50   6996.75    9950.00
6     C       g2   115.00   2606.00   4776.50   7673.25    9878.00


> str(result)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ group   : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3 1 2 3
 $ subgroup: Factor w/ 2 levels "g1","g2": 1 1 1 2 2 2
 $ value   : num [1:6, 1:5] 26 26 17 96 77 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "0%" "25%" "50%" "75%" ...
```

Comment: `result$value` is actually a matrix. You can however do `do.call(data.frame, result)` to fix it up. Or use an alternative system like `dplyr` or `data.table` which can deal better with this type of aggregation.